# Can't adjust brightness on Samsung RV420 with fn keys

Tags: kernel, brightness, samsung, function-keys

Typing `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` outputs

```
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
/sys/class/backlight/samsung/brightness
```

The max_brightness for the second is 8, but changing it with `echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/samsung/brightness` doesn't change brightness. I can do it by using intel_backlight: `echo 2000 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` (max_brightness: `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness` outputs 4648).

But I want to do this work with the fn brightness keys, as I always did. I don't know what happened to stop working, maybe the use of +1 monitor and removing it in a wrong time or a system update.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits in an Samsung RV420 notebook. Kernel Version is 3.2.0-27-generic.

Could you help me? Please tell me what more info should I provide.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the "related" questions on brightness that appear in the sidebar?  Not sure they will help, but generally you'll get good ideas that way.

Comment: yes, can't get a fix :s

Comment: Google 'samsung easy display option download' which will restore all fn functions. I'm pleased to say I have just done this to restore the brightness function etc. on my samsung RV520 and all now work.
Hope it works for you.
Conbrio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1028151) seems to have made its way into 3.2.0-27.

The only practical solution I found was to downgrade back to 3.2.0-26.

Assuming you previously had that kernel on this box and recently upgraded, you can boot this kernel temporarily via the grub2 menu:
* Reboot, and depress and hold the left-shift key until the boot menu appears.
* Select the previous versions menu.
* Choose 3.2.0-26 if available, or the latest (but pre- 3.2.0-27, of course.)

In the meantime if you're 'stuck in the dark,' I posted a [kludge](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1028151/comments/2) on the bug report that should let you temporarily restore max brightness.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! I booted with 3.2.0-26, now I can adjust brightness normally. A new boot version will ship soon, with this bug probally fixed, right? The trick with sudo tee also deal with the problem. Thanks. :)

Comment: Good to know that wasn't a bug with the use of another monitor. :)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't change graphics with <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys on my Acer laptop.

This helped me (notice a little bit different parameter), added to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Then run`update-grub` and `reboot`.

Source:
http://www.refreshit.info/2012/08/solved-brightness-increase-and-decrease.html